# Create a list in a list from a separate list, which contains the intervals as an integers

Tags: python, list

As the title suggests, I would like to create a list in a list from a second list.
For this I prepared the following example:

```
list1 = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15]
list2 = [3, 4, 2, 6]


solution = [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6, 7], [8, 9], [10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15]]
```

I have already found a solution, but I find it very cumbersome and I am sure there is a faster and easier solution to my problem.

```
list1 = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15]
list2 = [3, 4, 2, 6]

j = 0
solution= []

for i in list2:
    solution.append(list1[j:i+j])
    j += i
```

Thanks a lot already guys

Comment: I'm curious to see other answers as this seems reasonably straightforward to understand to me.

Comment: Well, it's possible to do with a list comprehension, but I'm not convinced it's actually faster or easier. `j=0; solution=[list1[j:(j:=i+j)] for i in list2]` (As you can see, it requires the walrus operator, which in my case means I probably would not do this in real life.)

Comment: Can you explain the walrus operator in more detail? I found a few articles online but they are quite complicated...

Comment: The walrus operator assigns the value and also returns it. `(j:=i+j)` assigns `i+j` to `j`, and the expression's value is also that same `i+j`.

Comment: Why hard when it can be easy - thank you for the straight answer

Comment: Here's another solution: `[list1[sum(list2[:i]): sum(list2[:i+1])] for i in range(len(list2))]`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

One possible solution is using [`itertools.islice`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.islice):

```py
from itertools import islice

list1 = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15]
list2 = [3, 4, 2, 6]

out = iter(list1)
out = [list(islice(out, v)) for v in list2]

print(out)
```

Prints:

```
[[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6, 7], [8, 9], [10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15]]
```

---

Another using `:=` operator:

```py
list1 = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15]
list2 = [3, 4, 2, 6]

out = 0
out = [list1[out:(out:=out+a)] for a in list2]

print(out)
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`more_itertools.split_into`](https://more-itertools.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#more_itertools.split_into):

```
# pip install more-itertools
from more_itertools import split_into

out = list(split_into(list1, list2))
```

Output:

```
[[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6, 7], [8, 9], [10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15]]
```

Like @Andrej's answer, it is based on an iterator and islice:

```
def split_into(iterable, sizes):
    it = iter(iterable)
    for size in sizes:
        if size is None:
            yield list(it)
            return
        else:
            yield list(islice(it, size))
```

A [numpy](/questions/tagged/numpy) equivalent would be:

```
import numpy as np

out = np.array_split(list1, np.cumsum(list2[:-1]))

# or to include the last number as split point
out = np.array_split(list1, np.cumsum(list2))
```

Output:

```
[array([1, 2, 3]),
 array([4, 5, 6, 7]),
 array([8, 9]),
 array([10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15])]

# with last split point
[array([1, 2, 3]),
 array([4, 5, 6, 7]),
 array([8, 9]),
 array([10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15]),
 array([], dtype=int64)]
```

Answer (score 1):

you could also use an iterator without itertools.islice by mapping the next function to repeated copies of the iterator:

```
list1 = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15]
list2 = [3, 4, 2, 6]

i1 = iter(list1)
solution = [[*map(next,[i1]*n)] for n in list2 ]

print(solution)
[[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6, 7], [8, 9], [10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15]]
```